# Subclassing CIFilter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

I'm trying to create a subclass of `CIFilter` as follows:

```
class ColorMonochromeFilter: CIFilter {

    required init(red: CGFloat!, green: CGFloat!, blue: CGFloat!) {

        super.init(name: "ColorMonochrome")
        setDefaults()

        let colour = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
        setValue(colour, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    }
}
```

I get the following error messages:

1. Class 'ColorMonochromeFilter' does not implement its superclass's
   required members
2. Must call a designated initializer of the
   superclass 'CIFilter'

It seems that the designated initialiser is `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` due to `CIFilter` conforming to `NSCoding` protocol, rather than `init(name: String!)` which is declared in an extension on `CIFilter`.

I can remove the first error by adding:

```
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

(although that seems a little superfluous!)

Is there a way to resolve the second issue?

---

What I'm trying to achieve here is the Swift equivalent of this:

```
@implementation ASHColorMonochromeFilter

    + (ASHColorMonochromeFilter *) filterWithRed: (CGFloat) red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue
    {
        ASHColorMonochromeFilter * filter = (ASHColorMonochromeFilter *)[ASHColorMonochromeFilter filterWithName: @"CIColorMonochrome"];

        UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed: red green: green blue: blue alpha: 1.0];
        [filter setValue: color forKey: kCIImageColorSpace];

        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really want to subclass CIFilter in order to add/override methods, or do you just need an additional initializer?

Comment: Well, in this case, I'd like to understand how to achieve the above, if it's possible - or if there's a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: I am not really an expert in this area, but as I understand it, `init(name: "ColorMonochrome")` loads a predefined filter, so subclassing that might not make sense. In a subclass you would just call `super.init()`. - If you just need an additional initializer for the ColorMonochrome filter then you can define an extension. (I have prepared an answer with an example, but I am not sure if that is what you need.)

Comment: I've updated my question to try and clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Objective-C class method

```
+ (ASHColorMonochromeFilter *) filterWithRed: (CGFloat) red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue
```

returns actually an instance of (a subclass) of `CIFilter`. The same can be achieved
in Swift with a convenience initializer

```
extension CIFilter {
     convenience init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) {
        self.init(name:"CIColorMonochrome")
        setDefaults()
        let colour = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
        setValue(colour, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    }
}
```

which is called as

```
let filter = CIFilter(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.3)
```

Comment: OK, that's fine, but what happens if I really *do* want to return a subclass? With extra properties, say? It seems like this is much harder in Swift than Objective-C in this case… or am I missing something?

Comment: @AshleyMills: Then you would just call super.init() in your subclass initializer. - Even in ObjC, `[ASHColorMonochromeFilter filterWithName:...` does *not* return an instance of your ASHColorMonochromeFilter class.

Comment: And there's the problem - the superclass (`CIFilter`) itself doesn't have a designated initialiser itself, but `init(coder: aDecoder)` through adopting `NSCoding`. So is it feasible to call `super.init(coder: nil)`?

Comment: @AshleyMills: as I said,  you would just call super.init in your subclasses initializer.